# Proving sequential compactness of set implies compactness in complex plane or $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

I understand the standard argument of proving these kind of statement in general metric space, that is: totally bounded & complete $\implies$ compact $\implies$ sequentially compact $\implies$ totally bounded & complete

Instead of this, in Euclidean spaces like complex or $\mathbb{R}^2$, even $\mathbb{R}^n$, I want the condition that closed and bounded $\implies$  sequentially compact $\implies$ compact $\implies$ closed and bounded.

However, I am stuck at showing sequentially compact $\implies$ compact .

My thought is arguing that every collection of open covers can be equal to countable union of open covers, and then prove by establishing a sequence $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ that belongs $U_n \backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} U_i$ and use sequential compactness to reach a contradiction.
But i was stuck at the step of showing collection of open covers to countable subcovers.
Will rational radius helps?
Any hints or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: This isn't the strategy you ask about, but a subset of a Euclidean space is bounded if and only if it is totally bounded, and is closed if and only if it is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall prove a lemma first.

Let $K$ be a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and let $\{A_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ be an open cover of $K$.

**Lemma:** If $K$ is sequentially compact, then there is some $\delta>0$ such that, for each $p\in K$, there is some $\lambda\in\Lambda$ such that $B_\delta(p)\subset A_\lambda$.

**Proof:** Suppose otherwise. Then, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, there is some $p_n\in K$ such that $B_{1/n}(p_n)$ is contained in no $A_\lambda$. It is being assumed that $K$ is sequentially compact and therefore some subsequence of $(p_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to some $p\in K$. Since $\{A_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ is an open cover of $K$, $p\in A_\lambda$, for some $\lambda\in\Lambda$, and, in fact, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $B_{1/N}(p)\subset A_\lambda$. If $n\geqslant2N$ is such that $|p-p_n|<\frac1{2N}$, then\begin{align}|q-p_n|<\frac1n&\implies|q-p|\leqslant|q-p_n|+|p_n-p|<\frac1N\\&\implies q\in B_{1/N}(p);\end{align}in other words, $B_{1/n}(p_n)\subset B_{1/N}(p)$. But then $B_{1/n}(p_n)\subset A_\lambda$, which is impossible, by the choice of $p_n$.

---

I will prove now that if $K$ is sequentially compact, then it is compact. Again, let $\{A_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ be an open cover of $K$. Let $\delta>0$ be as in the previous lemma. If the open cover had no finite subcover, then we could define a sequence $(p_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $K$ as follows:

- Let $p_1$ be any element of $K$ (if $K=\emptyset$, then *any* finite subset of the given cover would be an open subcover, and therefore $K\ne\emptyset$).
- If $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$ are chosen, then $\bigcup_{j=1}^kB_\delta(p_k)\not\supset K$ (since, for each $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$, there is some $\lambda_k\in\Lambda$ such that $B_\delta(p_n)\subset A_{\lambda_k}$ and then $\bigcup_{j=1}^kB_\delta(p_k)\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^kA_{\lambda_k}$, which, by assumption, does not contain $K$), and then you take some $p_{k+1}\in K\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^kB_\delta(p_k)$.

It follows from this definition that $(\forall m,n\in\Bbb N):m\ne n\implies\|p_m-p_n\|\geqslant\delta$. This proves that no subsequence of $(p_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, which is impossible, since $K$ is sequentially compact, and therefore $(p_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence.